# Cast reflected object to reflected generic interface

Tags: generics, reflection, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, entityframework.extended

I am working on a project that is built on .NET 4.5, EF5 and GenericRepository.EntityFramework. I am trying to create a publication service that will take some actions on records in an database used specifically for authoring and move

The first problem is that the cast of my types to `(IBaseRepository<BaseEntity>)` fails. 
I am successful when testing with the first repository (the one I listed in the sample DataBucket class below) by using a direct cast of...

```
object myRepository = p.GetValue(entity, null);  
IBaseRepository<MRClassification> risk = myRepository;
```

because myRepository takes a 'MRClassification' object type

The problem is that each repository are not of the same signature, is it possible to return a list of `IBaseRepository<p.PropertyType.GetInterfaces()[0].GenericTypeArguments[0]>` which will return me the entity that each repository takes as a type?

I thought about using covariance but I have methods in the BaseRepository that take T as a parameter like

```
public virtual new void Add(T entity) { do something; }
```

Publication App Code

```
    public static void DeactivateNonTransversableExpiredRecords()
    {
            IEnumerable<Tuple<IBaseRepository<BaseEntity>, Type>> nonTransversableList =
                GetNonTransversableRepositories(Databucket);

            foreach (var repository in nonTransversableList)
            {
                ////IQueryable recordsToExpire =
                    ////((IBaseRepository<BaseEntity>)repository).FindBy(
                    ////    p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.ExpirationDate).Date <= DateTime.Now.Date && p.IsActive);
                IQueryable recordsToExpire = repository.Item1.FindBy(p => p.IsActive);

                foreach (var row in recordsToExpire)
                {
                    ((BaseEntity)row).IsActive = false;
                    ((IBaseRepository<BaseEntity>)repository).Edit((BaseEntity)row);
                }
            }
        }


        private static IEnumerable<Tuple<IBaseRepository<BaseEntity>, Type>> GetNonTransversableRepositories(object entity)
        {

            PropertyInfo[] properties =
                entity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            List<Tuple<IBaseRepository<BaseEntity>, Type>> list = new List<Tuple<IBaseRepository<BaseEntity>, Type>>();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
            {
                if (!typeof(ITransversableRepository).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
                {
                    if (OpenGenericIsAssignableFrom(typeof(IBaseRepository<>), p.PropertyType))
                    {
                        list.Add(
                            new Tuple<IBaseRepository<BaseEntity>, Type>(
                                (IBaseRepository<BaseEntity>)Activator.CreateInstance(p.PropertyType),
                                p.GetValue(entity, null)));
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

POCO Entities and Repositories in DataModel Solution

```
    --- DataBucket
public class DataBucket : Audit, IDataBucket
{
    private IMRClassificationRepository mrClassCodeRepository;

    public IMRClassificationRepository MRClassificationRepository
    {
        get { return this.mrClassCodeRepository ?? (this.mrClassCodeRepository = new MRClassificationRepository(this.dataContext)); }
    }
    ...
}

--- Repository Class Headers
public class MRClassificationRepository : BaseRepository<MRClassification>, IMRClassificationRepository
{
    ...
}

public interface IMRClassificationRepository : IBaseRepository<MRClassification>
{
    ...
}   

public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : CoreRepository<T>, IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity, IBaseEntity
{
    ...
}
public interface IBaseRepository<T> : ICoreRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    ...
}   

--- Entity Class Headers
public class MRClassification : RiskClassification
{
    ...
}
public abstract class RiskClassification : Revisionable
{
    ...
}

public abstract class Revisionable : BaseEntity, IRevisionableEntity
{
    ...
}

public class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    ...
}

public interface IBaseEntity : IEntity<Guid>
{
    ...
}
```